# How to have Hocon configuration with dot in key name?

Tags: scala, config, typesafe, hocon

conf file :

```
hdfs {
 asd = 1
 asd.bla = 2 
}
```

when I m trying to load the config file

```
 config.getConfig("hdfs")
```

the keys are merged, and are not separeted

```
Config(SimpleConfigObject({"asd":{"bla":2}}))
```

Workaround to use conf file like this :

```
hdfs {
 asd = 1
 asd-bla = 2 
}

Config(SimpleConfigObject({"asd":1,"asd-bla":2}))
```

Answer (score 4):

It works as intended - see [specification of HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/main/HOCON.md#path-expressions).

```
hdfs {
 asd = 1
 asd.bla = 2 
}
```

is the same as

```
hdfs {
 asd = 1
 asd = {
  bla = 2 
 }
}
```

If you want a JSON behavior... use JSON syntax, including `""`:

```
hdfs {
 asd = 1
 "asd.bla" = 2 
}
```

Without quotes it will treat [dots as nested keys](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/main/HOCON.md#paths-as-keys)